# Where in the Vedas is the verse Sītā refers to in Ayodhyā Kāṇḍa found?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, identification-request, marriage, sita

In [Ayodhyā Kāṇḍa of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=2&field_sarga_value=29&field_sloka_value=17), while trying to convince Rāma that he should let her accompany him to the forest, Sītā makes the following statement wherein she refers to a verse/mantra from the Vedas.

Where exactly is this verse ('iha loke ca pitṛbhir yā strī ... pretya bhāve api tasya sā') found in the Vedas?

> प्रेत्यभावे हि कल्याण स्सङ्गमो मे सह त्वया। 
> श्रुतिर्हि श्रूयते पुण्या ब्राह्मणानां यशस्विनाम्।।2.29.17।।
>
> इहलोके च पितृभिर्या स्त्री यस्य महामते। 
> अद्भिर्दत्ता स्वधर्मेण प्रेत्यभावेऽपि तस्य सा।।2.29.18।।
>
> प्रेत्यभावेऽपि even after death, त्वया सह with you, मे to me, कल्याणः auspiciousness, सङ्गमः union, यशस्विनाम् by the famous, ब्राह्मणानाम् brahmins', पुण्या pious, **श्रुतिः statement from the Vedas**, **श्रूयते is heard**, महामते O highminded one, या स्त्री that woman, इह लोके in this world, पितृभिः by parents, यस्य to whom, स्वधर्मेण in accordance with one's own tradition, अद्भि: with waters, दत्ता is given, प्रेत्यभावेऽपि even after death, सा she, तस्य belongs to him.
>
> My union with you, O highminded one, is auspicious even beyond death. A woman, given away by her parents in accordance with traditional offerings of water belongs to him even after death and lives with him. **This is a statement from the Vedas quoted by famous brahmins.**

Comment: Is it C.E. version of Ramayana?

Comment: Yes, the same verse is in the CE also. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: RV X.18 or RV X.85 may give clue on this subject

Comment: If you are asking whether that shloka occurs verbatim in the Vedas, then the clear answer is no. The diction and grammar of the shloka is post-Vedic. And the idea that a wife must accompany her husband even after death is refuted in the Rig Veda 10.18.8, which tells the widow to get up from the side of the husband's dead body and return to the world of the living.

Comment: The above shlokas may be taken as argumentative rather than literal. Sita wants to somehow convince Rama so she couches generic sentiments of attachment and commitment in terms of appeal to Vedic authority.

Comment: @RamAbloh [One Ramayana commentator](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/commentaries?language=dv&field_commnetary_tid=8&field_kanda_tid=2&field_sarga_value=29) seems to think it's a Yajur mantra: "कुतः प्रेत्य च सङ्गमसिद्धिरित्यत्राहश्रुतिरित्यादि। ब्राह्मणानां मुखात् पुण्या किल श्रुतिः यत उक्तार्थप्रतिपादिका श्रूयते अत इत्यर्थः। का सेत्यतस्तां श्रुतिं पठतिइहेत्यादि। पद्यसिद्धये वाल्मीकिना महामत इति पदं प्रयुक्तम्। श्रुतिस्वरूपं तु तदतिरिक्तं **यजुर्मन्त्र**रूपम्इह लोके च पितृभिर्यास्त्री यस्याद्भिर्दत्ता स्वधर्मेण प्रेत्यभावेऽपि तस्य सेति ।। 18 ।।"

Comment: @sv. Interestingly, he doesn't actually quote any mantra though. And I looked at 3 other commentaries, and none of them mention that it is a Yajus mantra. They do not even emphasize that it is actually quoted from a Veda. https://archive.org/details/wg765/page/n195/mode/2up